# How to use Bonferroni correction - correct by no of parameters? No of models per dependent variable?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

I have a simple question about when corrections such as Bonferroni should be applied.

Say I have a research question for which I have three separate dependent variables, and run three separate models for each dependent variable, and in each model there are three parameters - In principle, how do I correct the alpha value?

Does one correct within a particular model (so here, the alpha value would be 0.05/3 for each model given each model has three parameters)?

Does one correct for the number of models AND the number of parameters per model for each dependent variable (so here the alpha value would be 0.05/9 since there are three dependent variables for each model, and three models per dependent variable)?

Does one correct for the number of models per research question AND the number of parameters per model (so here, I have three models for each of three dependent variables, each with three parameters, so alpha would be 0.05/27)?

I appreciate that this could keep scaling up for number of models/parameters across a whole paper, journal, life's work etc, which would be somewhat ridiculous, but is there a general precedent that should be followed?

Please do let me know if you need more specifics - hopefully the question should make sense though!

Thank you!

Comment: It is a matter of how many hypothesis tests you run. Whenever people talk about Bonferroni I wonder if they know that there are many other ways to adjust for multiple testing that are not as conservative.

Comment: Thank you Michael.  So effectively both the number of parameters and models then, given each parameter tested is a hypothesis test?  I'm using Bonferonni as it's convention in the discipline i'm moving into so usually expected by reviewers...  What else would you recommend as a less conservative option?

Comment: You could look at bootstrap or permutation methods. Look at the book by Westfall and Young.